# Custom function with vectors and matrixes in R

Tags: r, function, matrix, vector

I need to create a custom function in R that return the product between a vector of dimension m x 1 and a matrix of dimension m x m. However, the default value of the vector must be 0 and the default value of the matrix must be the identity matrix of dimension m x m.

I have worked creating basic functions in R like factorial or pow functions, but I have no idea how to create a function that involves vectors and matrixes.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean initialize the vector and matrix like below?

```
m <- 5
v <- matrix(0,m)
mat <- diag(m)
```

If you are looking for matrix production, try `%*%`, e.g.,

```
mat %in% v
```

Comment: Yes, those must be the default values of the function if the user does not enter an input.

Comment: @Aragorn64 see my update, which now includes matrix production